# How can I change color of column Header for a ListView using colordialog control

Tags: c#, listview

I know how to change header color of listview before runtime. i.e., in code I wrote like this :

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Pink, e.Bounds);
    e.DrawText();
}
```

As I cannot place the screenshots here, am just trying to explain here. In WindowsForm I placed  ListView, ColorDialog and ContextMenuStrip. I added Header for ListView. Now when running the application when user right click on the ListView and select color option, ColorDialog box will be Opened. When the user Select one Color and press Ok button, that color should be applied to the Header of the ListView. This is my Requirement.

I have tried, but i did not get any relevant answers. So i came here. Any answers will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

After changing my code:

```
private void BackColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DialogResult res=colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
         if (res==DialogResult.OK)
         {
              hdr=colorDialog1.Color;
              listView1.Update();
         }
    }
```

And i changed my listView1_DrawColumnHeader event i changed as:

```
        using (Brush hBr=new SolidBrush(hdr))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hBr, e.Bounds);
            e.DrawText();
        }
```

But the problem is that it is taking nearly 2 minutes to change to the given color. Can you help me plz

Comment: Well, if a color dialog is involved the color is being picked at runtime.  Save the color to a var and use that in your code.

Comment: @Plutonix Ok I saved in var. But how can we pass that var to the listView1_DrawColumnHeader event? I am beginner, please help me out.

Comment: update your post to show what you did/tried

Comment: @Plutonix Can You Please help me now, I updated my Requirement

Comment: how many items are in the LV when that happens? Does it work with just zero or 1 item?  As OwnerDraw, you also have to handle `DrawItem` maybe the bottleneck is there.

Comment: listView1.Update() doesn't do anything, nothing needs updating.  You need to call listView1.Invalidate() instead.

Comment: There are no items in the ListView. But Timer is running. But i think its not the problem, because the GridView present in my application is changing its color fastly. But in ListView case it is slowing down.
And i dont have any idea how to handle DrawItem.

Comment: @HansPassant There is no difference, when i placed listView1.Invalidate() also takes much time to change from one color to another..

Comment: `Invalidate()` is correct, I did not notice that in your code.  If you are not also handling DrawItem, the items wont draw.  When you decide on OwnerDraw, you have to do ALL the drawing, not just the parts you want to change.  In this case it would just be `e.DrawDefault = true;` but it needs to be there.  Otherwise, it is hard to say why it is slow, I dont have your code, data etc.  If you are doing something time consuming in a short timer, that could be the problem.  Disable that to see if it is the problem.

Comment: I have Two headings in ListView Header i.e., listView1.Columns[0].Text = "Latitude"; and listView1.Columns[1].Text = "Longitude";
When I applied color, first longitude changes & after some time Latitude is changing. I disabled timer but no result.

Comment: It should paint Col(1) right after Col(0), before painting items, but I would see to that before I go looking elsewhere for a problem.  (You add DrawSubItem handler to handle both items and subitems) Also try this on a simple, minimal, just a 2 col LV to make sure it is not something else somewhere in your code that is the issue.  Beyond this, I am just guessing.

Comment: @Plutonix Here is my actual problem in that code I found, when the mouse is placing on header of the LV only it is changing color. So can you fix it please?

Comment: If you start a new project with a LV with several columns, you can test that the code below does work as expected (*with* DrawSubItem handled). It sounds like Something somewhere in other parts of your code is interfering or interrupting stuff. Did you change `Update` to `Invalidate` (sounds like maybe not!)? I just have nothing to go on.   Just post a new question focusing on the new issue.

Comment: Ok Thanks, for any new issues i'll post for Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you saved the user's desired color into a Color var, here named `hdrColor`.  To use it:

```
// form level var with a default:
Color hdrColor = SystemColors.Control;

private void _DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    using (Brush hBr = new SolidBrush(hdrColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hBr, e.Bounds);
        e.DrawText();
    }
}
```

You cannot "pass" it to the event without destroying the event signature.  So, just save the *desired color* from the color dialog to a class level variable, create a brush from it, and use it in the paint event.  Note that `using` disposes of the brush when we are done with it.

[image] [image]

Comment: Now I changed my code like this

private void headerBackColorToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             DialogResult result = colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
             if (result == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                  hdr = colorDialog1.Color;
                  listView1.Update();
             }
        }
And in my listView1_DrawColumnHeader event i changed as:

            using (Brush hBr = new SolidBrush(hdr))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hBr, e.Bounds);
            }

Comment: code doesnot format on comments and I cant read that. [Edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27785000/edit) to update/change your question